# Changing Reference in custom MSBuild task not having expected effect

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have written a custom task that implements Task for use with MSBuild. The idea is that it changes various Reference HintPaths. I realize that there are simpler ways to do this using conditions, but automated tools like updating NuGet packages don't play nicely with them.

I call my task like so:

```
<Target Name="ChangeReferences">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="&lt;&lt;&lt; %Reference.HintPath)" />

    <ChangeReferences References='@(Reference)'>
        <Output ItemName="Reference" TaskParameter="Result" />
    </ChangeReferences>

    <Message Importance="High" Text="&gt;&gt;&gt; %Reference.HintPath)" />
</Target>
```

The result (edited) is as expected:

```
4>  <<< ..\packages\MyProject.1.0.0\lib\net462\MyProject.dll
.
.
.
4>  >>> C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug\MyProject.dll
```

However, this has no effect on the DLL that was imported. OK, I thought, there are some obvious possible explanations:

1. The DLL was already imported before the Task was executed
2. This field is informational, but is not used

So I set the HintPath to a nonsense value, thinking if either explanation was true, it would have no effect. But lo and behold, the reference was not found! So it appears to have an effect only when it is a bad one.

This has thrown me completely. I'm happy to include more data if there is anything else that may help, but I think this may be cluttered already.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your discovery here. You can mark it as answer so that more members with similar issue will benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the assignment. It doesn't write over Reference the way I would expect. It seems to keep a duplicate.